# Merge Sorted array Error in c++: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/
In this leetcode question, this is the logic, I used

```
class Solution {
public:
void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    vector<int> ans;
    
    while (i<m && j<n) {
        
        if (nums1[i] < nums2[j]){
            ans[k++] = nums1[i++];
            
        }
        else {
            ans[k++] = nums2[j++];
            
        }
    }           
    while (i<m) {
        ans[k++] = nums1[i++];
        
    }            
    while (j<n) {
        ans[k++] = nums2[j++];
    }        
    for (int h = 0; h<(m+n); h++) {
        nums1[h] = ans[h];
    }
    }
    };
```

while running the code, I get this runtime error.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2hRU.png)
How do I solve this

Comment: `void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) { std::vector<int> ans; std::merge(nums1.begin(), nums1.begin() + m, nums2.begin(), nums2.begin() + n, std::back_inserter(ans)); nums1 = ans;}`.  -- *How do I solve this* -- By learning the available algorithm functions, such as [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a vector of size zero

```
vector<int> ans;
```

This code attempts to change an element of the size zero vector.

```
ans[k++] = nums1[i++];
```

That's the cause of your error.

If you want to add an element to the end of a vector use `push_back`

```
ans.push_back(nums1[i++]);
```

C++ vectors don't change size automatically, you have to use `push_back` or `resize` or `insert` or something similar.

Alternatively make the vector the correct size to begin with

```
vector<int> ans(m + n);
```

though I prefer the `push_back` method myself.